# R dyplr::complete nesting with part of combination

Tags: r, dataframe, combinations, expand

first time I post after two weeks of trying everything.
I need to complete a set of data (500 000 lines) for graph.

For the example, there is 3 parkings and different type of car per parking. When there is no line, its mean there was 0 of this type of car regarding the date (important for the graph), so I complete the data combinaison.
Except the result include all the car type of all the parking which is to much for the size of the data.
How can I complete the correct set of combinaison / or filter after doing the expand ?

```
parking_data <- data.frame(
 parking_id = c (1,1,1,2,2,2,3),
 parking_date = as.Date(c("2022-01-01", "2022-01-01", "2022-01-02", "2022-01-01","2022-01-01","2022-01-02","2022-01-01")),
 parking_name = c("First floor","First floor","First floor","Second floor","Second floor","Second floor","Third floor"),
 parking_type_car = c("Toyota","Ford","Toyota","Toyota","Volvo","Volvo","Chevrolet"),
 parking_type_car_nb = c(2,1,2,1,3,3,4)
)

parking_data<-complete(parking_data,nesting(parking_date,parking_id,parking_name),parking_type_car,fill=list(parking_type_car_nb=0),explicit = FALSE)
```

At the end for example, the parking n.3 should have only the Chevrolet, and the parking n.1 et n.2 shouldn't have the Chevrolet. The car type shouldn't get mixe up between each parking except if one of them have already been there.

I try also 2 x group nesting inside tidyr::complete, no effect.

Any idea or tips ?

Thanks by advance

OUPUT :

```
DATE           ID     NAME         CAR TYPE    COUNT  
2022-01-01     3    Third floor    Chevrolet    4
2022-01-01     3    Third floor    Ford         0
2022-01-01     3    Third floor    Toyota       0
2022-01-01     3    Third floor    Volvo        0
2022-01-01     2    Second floor   Chevrolet    0
2022-01-01     2    Second floor   Ford         0
2022-01-01     2    Second floor   Toyota       1
2022-01-01     2    Second floor   Volvo        3
2022-01-02     2    Second floor   Chevrolet    0
2022-01-02     2    Second floor   Ford         0
2022-01-02     2    Second floor   Toyota       0
2022-01-02     2    Second floor   Volvo        3
2022-01-01     1    First floor    Chevrolet    0
2022-01-01     1    First floor    Ford         1
2022-01-01     1    First floor    Toyota       2
2022-01-01     1    First floor    Volvo        0
2022-01-02     1    First floor    Chevrolet    0
2022-01-02     1    First floor    Ford         0
2022-01-02     1    First floor    Toyota       2
2022-01-02     1    First floor    Volvo        0
```

OUPUT EXPECTED:

```
DATE           ID     NAME         CAR TYPE    COUNT  
2022-01-01     3    Third floor    Chevrolet    4
2022-01-01     2    Second floor   Toyota       1
2022-01-01     2    Second floor   Volvo        3
2022-01-02     2    Second floor   Toyota       0
2022-01-02     2    Second floor   Volvo        3
2022-01-01     1    First floor    Ford         1
2022-01-01     1    First floor    Toyota       2
2022-01-02     1    First floor    Ford         0
2022-01-02     1    First floor    Toyota       2
```

Comment: FWIW `complete` is from `tidyr` and not `dplyr`

Comment: Can you include your expected output? It's not clear to me how the output should vary from the starting data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I edit Tidyr and add the ouput expected. I got 7 rows before complete, after complete i got 25, i need only 9.

Comment: Do you want `complete(parking_data, parking_date, nesting(parking_id,parking_name,parking_type_car),fill=list(parking_type_car_nb=0),explicit = FALSE)`? That is 10 lines b/c Chevrolet zero on 3rd floor noted on 2022-01-02

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if if you might be looking for a slight variation on the output expected. This will produce for every date an entry for every id/name/type that combination that exists in the data.

```
complete(parking_data, parking_date, 
         nesting(parking_id,parking_name,parking_type_car),
         fill=list(parking_type_car_nb=0),explicit = FALSE)

# A tibble: 10 × 5
   parking_date parking_id parking_name parking_type_car parking_type_car_nb
   <date>            <dbl> <chr>        <chr>                          <dbl>
 1 2022-01-01            1 First floor  Ford                               1
 2 2022-01-01            1 First floor  Toyota                             2
 3 2022-01-01            2 Second floor Toyota                             1
 4 2022-01-01            2 Second floor Volvo                              3
 5 2022-01-01            3 Third floor  Chevrolet                          4
 6 2022-01-02            1 First floor  Ford                               0
 7 2022-01-02            1 First floor  Toyota                             2
 8 2022-01-02            2 Second floor Toyota                             0
 9 2022-01-02            2 Second floor Volvo                              3
10 2022-01-02            3 Third floor  Chevrolet                          0
```

Comment: I try already this way, either i get all the car type, either i get all the date. For this example is fair, but for my 500 000 lines is not. Imagine 500 différents parking with 600 differents dates, if the date are duplicates.. Its a lot

Comment: It's unclear to me what logic gets your desired result. What is the rationale to add 2022-01-02 | 2 | Toyota and 2022-01-02 | 1 | Ford but not 2022-01-02 | 3 | Chevrolet?

Comment: In this example there is only two dates, so no impact on the result.
Try with this data : 
parking_data <- data.frame(
 parking_id = c (1,1,1,2,2,2,3),
 parking_date = as.Date(c("2022-01-01", "2022-01-04", "2022-01-05", "2022-01-03","2022-01-07","2022-01-07","2022-01-08")),
 parking_name = c("First floor","First floor","First floor","Second floor","Second floor","Second floor","Third floor"),
 parking_type_car = c("Toyota","Ford","Toyota","Toyota","Volvo","Volvo","Chevrolet"),
 parking_type_car_nb = c(2,1,2,1,3,3,4)
)

Comment: There is maybe a way to filter after this result, to remove all the extra row with only for the car type which are  0 everytime  :
`
parking_data <- parking_data %>% group_by(parking_type_car ) %>% filter (sum(parking_type_car_nb)>0)
`